# Decimal format to numeric notation

Tags: php

I would like to convert a double like "25695.256" to the scientific notation : "2.5695256E4" in PHP. I've found a lot of PHP function to force decimal format but no function to force scientific format. Have you an idea ?

Best regards

Comment: Use sprint() with the `e` format switch: `echo sprintf('%e', $value);`

Comment: @MarkBaker I came here to give that as an answer, I was beaten to it. Post it as an answer mate ;)

Comment: @sg3s - I always reckon that if it can be answered in fewer characters than a tweet, then it's only worth posting as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I've found. I have to use this code :

```
echo sprintf("%.". $decimals ."e", $value);
```

$decimals is the number of decimals to show.